# While loop that's meant to be infinite freezes after first cycle

Tags: python, while-loop, primes, infinite

My goal is to make a program that prints onscreen all of the prime numbers it can find, however I have this issue where the while loop runs only once, instead of repeating forever.

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    if num == 2:
        return True
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return False
    i = 3
    while i * i <= num:
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
            i += 2

x = 1
while True:
    x += 1
    if isPrime(x):
        print (x)
```

I also have tried adding `print("You can see this.")` at the very end of the code, and it runs, but only once.
I'm sure it's a common mistake, since Python is very strict on indentation, but could you guys help me discover it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `i +=2` is indented too deep, the inner loop never quits.

It should read

```
while i * i <= num:
    if num % i == 0:
        return False
    i += 2
```

Otherwise `i` never increases and the loop goes on and on and on.

Comment: Can you rephrase that? I van't quite understand what you mean, sorry...

Comment: Oh that was a dumb mistake by me... thank you. Still doesn't work though...

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return True` at the very end, after and outside the final loop. Otherwise the function ends without explicitly returning anything, so it implicitly returns `None` which is interpreted as false.